# Oracle sql query to find columns which has special character as value

Tags: sql, oracle, oracle11g

I have table with lot of columns where some of the columns values contains , as special character.

I looked at examples where it uses regex_like but I don't want values for columns. I just need the column names which contains value , as special character.

```
column1  column2   column3
abc,      pqr      def,
xyz       mno      ghi
```

Query for above data should return column1 and column3. Can someone help with the query to get the output as column1 and column3?

Appreciate your help.

Comment: What is your question?

Comment: how many columns are in your table?

Comment: I have 161 columns in the table

Comment: What is the expected output? Does it contain one row (combined list of column names across all rows) or two rows (one for each row).

Comment: Expected output should contain one row with list of all column names

Comment: Whats the end goal here, to identify and thus remove the commas?

Comment: identify the columns. no need to remove commas

Answer (score 1):

If you want to identify the columns that have commas, you can do something like this:

```
select 'column1'
from t
where column1 like '%,%'
group by 1
union all
select 'column2'
from t
where column2 like '%,%'
group by 1
union all
. . .
```

This will return a list of the column names that have commas in them.

You can also do this in a `select`:

```
select ((case when sum(case when column1 like '%,%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'column1; ' end) ||
        (case when sum(case when column2 like '%,%' then 1 else 0 end) > 0 then 'column2; ' end) ||
        . . .
       )
from t;
```

You can construct either of these queries using `all_tab_cols` and either a SQL query or spreadsheet.

Comment: I tried your first query. But it is generatign duplicate values.

Comment: @user2961454 . . . Really?  I tried the logic on Oracle 11g and it returned each value once.  Can you set up a SQL Fiddle?  Are you sure you have single quotes in the `select`?

Answer (score 1):

Not knowing how exactly the result would be used, I would consider constructing the query dynamically (since the number of columns is big).

You could use a function like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION get_columns(
    p_table_name IN VARCHAR2,
    p_substring IN VARCHAR2)
  RETURN VARCHAR2
IS
  stmt   VARCHAR2(32767) := 'SELECT ';
  result VARCHAR2(32767);
  CURSOR cols IS
    SELECT column_name
    FROM user_tab_columns
    WHERE table_name = upper(p_table_name)
      AND data_type = 'VARCHAR2';
BEGIN
  FOR i IN cols LOOP
    stmt := stmt || 'DECODE(SUM(CASE WHEN ' || i.column_name|| ' LIKE ''%' ||
    p_substring || '%'' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END),0,NULL,''' || i.column_name ||
    ','') || ';
  END LOOP;
stmt := SUBSTR(stmt, 1, LENGTH(stmt) - 3) || ' FROM your_table';
EXECUTE immediate(stmt) INTO result;
RETURN result;
END;
/
```

which you could call like this:

```
SELECT get_columns('your_table', ',')
FROM dual;
```

Just an idea.  If the approach works for you, you will probably want to make some changes.

Answer (score 0):

Going with @Carlos De Leon's approach of using a function to dinamically generate the query, and using xmlquery to do it in SQL:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_return_columns (p_owner      IN VARCHAR2,
                                              p_table_name IN VARCHAR2)
RETURN CLOB AS
  v_dyn_query clob;
  v_return    clob;
BEGIN
  WITH t AS (
  SELECT owner,
         table_name,
         ('SELECT listagg(column_names, '', '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_names) column_names
    FROM (SELECT column_names, count_vals
            FROM (SELECT ') sql1,
         decode(rn, 1, null, lpad(' ', 22)) || 'SUM(regexp_count(' || column_name || ', ''[^[:alnum:]]'')) ' || column_name || comma sql2,
         '                  FROM ' || owner || '.' || table_name || ')
            UNPIVOT (
                    count_vals for column_names in (' sql3,
         decode(rn, 1, null, lpad(' ', 49)) || column_name || comma sql4,
         lpad(' ', 49) || ')
                    )
         )
   WHERE count_vals > 0' sql5,
         rn
    FROM (SELECT c.owner,
                 c.table_name,
                 c.column_name,
                 nvl2(lead(c.column_id) over(PARTITION BY c.owner, c.table_name ORDER BY c.column_id ASC), ',' || chr(10), chr(10)) comma,
                 row_number() over (order by c.COLUMN_ID) rn
            FROM dba_tab_columns c
           WHERE c.owner = upper(p_owner)
             AND table_name = upper(p_table_name)
         )
       )
  SELECT dbms_xmlgen.convert((
         xmlquery('//text()' passing
           xmlconcat(
             xmlelement("Resultado", xmlattributes(1 as "rn"), sql1),
             xmlelement("Resultado", xmlattributes(2 as "rn"),
                                     xmlquery('//text()' passing xmlagg(xmlelement("sql2", sql2 || ' ') ORDER BY rn) returning content)
                       ),
             xmlelement("Resultado", xmlattributes(3 as "rn"), sql3),
             xmlelement("Resultado", xmlattributes(4 as "rn"),
                                     xmlquery('//text()' passing xmlagg(xmlelement("sql4", sql4 || ' ') ORDER BY rn) returning content)
                       ),
             xmlelement("Resultado", xmlattributes(5 as "rn"), sql5)
                       )
           returning content
         )).getclobval(), 1) as dyn_query
    INTO v_dyn_query
    FROM t
   GROUP BY sql1,
            sql3,
            sql5,
            owner,
            table_name;
  EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_dyn_query INTO v_return;

  RETURN v_return;
END;
```

Sample running:

```
SQL> create table t1 (column1 varchar2(100),
  2                   column2 varchar2(100),
  3                   column3 varchar2(100),
  4                   column4 varchar2(100),
  5                   column5 varchar2(100));
Table created
SQL> insert into t1 values ('abc,', 'pqr', 'def,', 'xxx', 'yyy');
1 row inserted
SQL> insert into t1 values ('xyz', 'mno', 'ghi,', 'xxx', 'z,zz');
1 row inserted
SQL> commit;
Commit complete

SQL> 
SQL> CREATE OR REPLACE FUNCTION fn_return_columns (p_owner      IN VARCHAR2,
  2                                                p_table_name IN VARCHAR2)
  3  RETURN CLOB AS
  4    v_dyn_query clob;
  5    v_return    clob;
  6  BEGIN
  7    WITH t AS (
  8    SELECT owner,
  9           table_name,
 10           ('SELECT listagg(column_names, '', '') WITHIN GROUP (ORDER BY column_names) column_names
 11      FROM (SELECT column_names, count_vals
 12              FROM (SELECT ') sql1,
 13           decode(rn, 1, null, lpad(' ', 22)) || 'SUM(regexp_count(' || column_name || ', ''[^[:alnum:]]'')) ' || column_name || comma sql2,
 14           '                  FROM ' || owner || '.' || table_name || ')
 15              UNPIVOT (
 16                      count_vals for column_names in (' sql3,
 17           decode(rn, 1, null, lpad(' ', 49)) || column_name || comma sql4,
 18           lpad(' ', 49) || ')
 19                      )
 20           )
 21     WHERE count_vals > 0' sql5,
 22           rn
 23      FROM (SELECT c.owner,
 24                   c.table_name,
 25                   c.column_name,
 26                   nvl2(lead(c.column_id) over(PARTITION BY c.owner, c.table_name ORDER BY c.column_id ASC), ',' || chr(10), chr(10)) comma,
 27                   row_number() over (order by c.COLUMN_ID) rn
 28              FROM dba_tab_columns c
 29             WHERE c.owner = upper(p_owner)
 30               AND table_name = upper(p_table_name)
 31           )
 32         )
 33    SELECT dbms_xmlgen.convert((
 34           xmlquery('//text()' passing
 35             xmlconcat(
 36               xmlelement("Resultado", xmlattributes(1 as "rn"), sql1),
 37               xmlelement("Resultado", xmlattributes(2 as "rn"),
 38                                       xmlquery('//text()' passing xmlagg(xmlelement("sql2", sql2 || ' ') ORDER BY rn) returning content)
 39                         ),
 40               xmlelement("Resultado", xmlattributes(3 as "rn"), sql3),
 41               xmlelement("Resultado", xmlattributes(4 as "rn"),
 42                                       xmlquery('//text()' passing xmlagg(xmlelement("sql4", sql4 || ' ') ORDER BY rn) returning content)
 43                         ),
 44               xmlelement("Resultado", xmlattributes(5 as "rn"), sql5)
 45                         )
 46             returning content
 47           )).getclobval(), 1) as dyn_query
 48      INTO v_dyn_query
 49      FROM t
 50     GROUP BY sql1,
 51              sql3,
 52              sql5,
 53              owner,
 54              table_name;
 55    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE v_dyn_query INTO v_return;
 56  
 57    RETURN v_return;
 58  END;
 59  /
Function created
SQL> SET LONG 99999
SQL> SELECT fn_return_columns(user, 'T1') from dual;
FN_RETURN_COLUMNS(USER,'T1')
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
COLUMN1, COLUMN3, COLUMN5
```